# How to use .net core + typescript + webpack + npm module with a function in Visual studio 2019?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, npm, webpack

I have created a simple npm module:

**lib.js:**

```
var myMath = function(a, b){
    //this.sum = a + b;
    return a + b;
};
    export default myMath;
```

lib.d.ts:

```
export var MyMath: (x: number, y: number) => number;
```

I have this in package.json:
  "types": "lib.d.ts"

I am trying to use it in a .net core project with Typescript and Webpack, but I get errors.
I can use it in js file, but I don't know how to do it in typescript.
May be declaration file is not good?

**and error :**

> mymathts1_1.MyMath is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by exporting with **export default myMath** in the .d.ts file also;